# Is $X$ has a strong rank 1-diagonal?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, article-writing

> **Definition 1:** A space $X$ has a strong rank 1-diagonal \cite{5} if there exists a
>   sequence $\{\mathcal U_n: n\in \omega\}$ of open covers of $X$ such
>   that for each $x\in X$, $\{x\}=\bigcap
> \{\overline{\operatorname{St}(x, \mathcal U_n}): n\in \omega\}$.
>
> **Example 2:** Let $Y=\bigcup\{[0,1]\times\{n\}:n \in \omega\}$ and $X=Y\cup\{a\}$
>   where $a \notin Y.$ Define a basis for a topology on $X$ as follows.
>   Basic open sets containing $a$ take the form $\{a \}\cup \bigcup
> \{[0,1)\times {m}: m \geq n \}$ where $n \in \omega.$ Basic open
>   sets about the other points of $X$ are the usual induced metric open
>   sets.
>
> **Question 3: Is $X$ has a strong rank 1-diagonal?**
>
> **Proof:** Construct a sequence $\{\mathcal V_n: n\in \omega\}$
>   of open covers of $Y$ which witnesses that $Y$ has a strong rank
>   1-diagonal. Let $\mathcal U_n= \mathcal V_n \cup (\{a \}\cup \bigcup
> \{[0,1)\times {m}: m \geq n \})$. Then $\{\mathcal U_n: n\in
> \omega\}$ shows that $X$ has a strong rank 1-diagonal.

I'm not sure the proof is OKey. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is fine. You could even replace $[0,1)$ in $\{a\}\cup\bigcup\big\{[0,1)\times\{m\}:m\ge n\big\}$ with $[0,1]$, as can be seen directly or by the following argument.

$X$ is obtained in an especially simple fashion from a compact metric space, which of course has a strong rank $1$ diagonal. Let me construct it a little differently. For $n\in\omega$ let $$Y_n=\left[0,\frac1{2^n}\right]\times\left\{\frac1{2^n}\right\}\;,$$ let $$Y=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}Y_n\;,$$  let $a=\langle 0,0\rangle$, and let $X=Y\cup\{a\}$. Let $\tau$ be the topology that $X$ inherits from the plane; $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is evidently a compact metric space.

Now let $D=\left\{\left\langle 0,\frac1{2^n}\right\rangle:n\in\omega\right\}$, and let $\tau'$ be the topology generated by the subbase $\tau\cup\{X\setminus D\}$; it’s not hard to check that $\tau'=\tau\cup\{U\setminus D:U\in\tau\}$, and that $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is homeomorphic to your space $X$. It is of course not regular, since $a$ cannot be separated from the closed set $D$.

However, it has the same closures of open sets as $\langle X,\tau\rangle$: if $U\in\tau$, then $\operatorname{cl}_\tau U=\operatorname{cl}_{\tau'}U$ and $\operatorname{cl}_\tau (U\setminus D)=\operatorname{cl}_{\tau'}(U\setminus D)$. It follows immediately that a family of $\tau$-open covers witnessing the fact that $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ has a strong rank $1$ diagonal does the same for $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a point I cannot pass, i.e., how could $Y=\bigcup Y_n$ be true?

Comment: @Paul: I’m defining $Y$ to be $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}Y_n$. Each of my spaces $Y_n$ is homeomorphic to your $[0,1]\times\{n\}$, and my $Y$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]\times\omega$, just as your $Y$ is. $X$ is actually just the one-point compactification.

Comment: I know that you want to show that $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\Bbb R$, and hence it is metrizable. However, the basic open set of $a=\langle 0,0 \rangle$ is not homeomorphic to the open set of the form like $\{a \}\cup \bigcup \{[0,1)\times {m}: m \geq n \}$.

Comment: @Paul: Now I see the problem: I didn’t see that you had used $[0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$ in defining nbhds of $a$. Of course you’re right: my space **is** different. I have to go away for a while; when I get back, I’ll either fix this or delete it.

Comment: $X$ is not compact, since it has an infinite  countable closed discrete subset $\{1 \times \{n\}\}$ of $X$. Is it right?

Comment: Okay. Thanks Brain for your time.